# Quorum node crashes during sending a private transaction

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, quorum

I am using 7NodeExample, quorum version 2.0.2, constellation version 0.3.2.

I have deployed a private contract say *Private-Con* from ***node 1***, providing **privateFor** parameter of ***node 2***. Now I am sending a private transaction on the contract from ***node 2*** providing **privateFor** parameter of ***node 1***.

It fails and ***node 2*** is crashing and not able to start again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to move to the latest [quorum version 2.2.3](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/releases) with the improved transaction control and explore [tessera](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/tessera) transaction manager instead of [constellation](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/constellation) for the private transactions.